How to Hide/Unhide Worksheet based on Cell Dropdown
First off, I am very new to VBA and coding in general. If you could explain what the code does, I would be very appreciative. I don't plan on using VBAs often and will probably get lost if I ever look at the code again.
I am trying to create an interactive Stormwater Calculation Excel workbook that will unhide certain sheets based on a dropdown list. I have created excel templates for different stormwater controls (sediment trap, sediment basin, wet pond, swale, etc.). Ideally, all of these would be hidden and when the user selects from a drop down which control measure they want to use, that sheet would become visible.
I just don't know the best way around this. In my head I imagine something along the lines of (and I know this is a very broken code)
    For Each cell in Range("C10:C15")
    If Cell.Value = text then
    Worksheets(Cell.Value).Visible = True

And then I hit a wall and don't know what to do. I want the code to read the value in each cell from C10:C15 and turn on
the sheet that has the same name.
Am I on the right track? Would putting the sheet names in an array make the code any easier?
How do I re-hide the sheet if the user goes backs and unselects it from the dropdown? Is it possible to build in hide function?
    If a sheet within array {Sediment Trap, Sediment Basin, Wet Pond, Swale} is not selected in C10:c15 then
    worksheets(Not_in_C10:C15).Visible = false


Loop through cells in C10:C15 to show sheets, and then hidden all other sheets.
Sub Demo()
    Dim c As Range, oDic As Object, oSht As Object
    Set oDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C10:C15") '  modify sheetname as needed
        If SheetExists(c.Value) Then ' Check if the sheet is exist
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(c.Value).Visible = True
            oDic(c.Value) = ""
        End If
    Next c
    For Each oSht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If Not oDic.exists(oSht.Name) Then oSht.Visible = False
    Next oSht
End Sub


Function SheetExists(strName As String, Optional wBook As Workbook)
    Dim sh As Object
    If wBook Is Nothing Then Set wBook = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sh = wBook.Sheets(strName)
    SheetExists = (Err = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function



Another option is to use Change event.
Right click on sheet tab > View Code > insert code as below
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range, Rng As Range
    Const DATA_RNG = "C10:C15"
    Set Rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range(DATA_RNG))
    If Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim oDic As Object, oSht As Object
    Set oDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In Me.Range(DATA_RNG)
        If SheetExists(c.Value) Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(c.Value).Visible = True
            oDic(c.Value) = ""
        End If
    Next
    For Each oSht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If Not oDic.exists(oSht.Name) Then oSht.Visible = False
    Next oSht
End Sub

Function SheetExists(strName As String, Optional wBook As Workbook)
    Dim sh As Object
    If wBook Is Nothing Then Set wBook = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sh = wBook.Sheets(strName)
    SheetExists = (Err = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function




You'll also save yourself some confusion in your code by noticing @taller's example above and understanding how to avoid using Select and fully qualifying cell and range references.
